# Derive the equation of a 3d circle given its center, radius and normal vector

Tags: geometry

How to derive the equation of a 3d circle given its center, radius, and normal vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the center is $\mathbf{c}$, radius is $r$, normal is $\mathbf{n}$. Find any two unit vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$ which are orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$ and to each other. Then the circle is given by $\mathbf{f}(t) = \mathbf{c} + \cos(t) \mathbf{u} + \sin(t) \mathbf{v}$ where $0 \le t < 2 \pi$.

To find suitable vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, one method is to let $\mathbf{n} = (x,y,z)$ and then pick $\tilde{\mathbf{u}} = (-y, x, 0)$. Then $\tilde{\mathbf{u}}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{n}$, so we can use $\mathbf{u} = \frac{\tilde{\mathbf{u}}}{\|\tilde{ \mathbf{u}}\|}$. After that, we could use $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{n} \times \mathbf{u}$ (cross product).